# Multiple logical OR Operators in Jade

Tags: node.js, pug, logical-operators

Very simple:
I want to make an `<img>`-Tag if the mimetype of my file is an image

```
case comment.fileType
  when "image/png" || "image/gif" || "image/jpeg"
    img(src="/files/#{comment.fileLink}")
```

does not work

It works for png, but not for jpeg or gif.
Is there a trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
case comment.fileType
  when "image/png"
  when "image/gif"
  when "image/jpeg"
    img(src="/files/#{comment.fileLink}")
```